# Error in converting a JSON file to AVRO

Tags: hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, avro

I'm following the instruction on [AVRO](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/mr.html) website and create a json and a schema file as follows (both are in text files):

JSON file

```
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color": "red"}
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color": "green"}
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color": "purple"}
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color": null}
```

and the schema file:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
"type": "record",
"name": "User",
"fields": [
{"name": "name", "type": "string"},
{"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
{"name":"favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
]
}
```

When I try to create the avro file using the `avro-tools` jar file, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-uni
on. Got VALUE_STRING
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.error(JsonDecoder.java:697)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readIndex(JsonDecoder.java:441)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:29
0)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:2
67)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.ja
va:155)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumRead
er.java:193)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumRea
der.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.ja
va:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.ja
va:142)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileWriteTool.run(DataFileWriteTool.java:99)

    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:84)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

Could someone help me figuring this out. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Correct the first three rows of your JSON input as shown below and try.

```
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color":{"string": "red"}}
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color":{"string": "green"}}
{"name": "user", "favorite_number": null, "favorite_color":{"string":"purple"}}
```